# Count Sets of Data

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a data table that is formatted like this:

[image]

I am wanting to show the Walkthrough Completed counts of each ToD on a given day. Walkthrough Completed can be In-Progress or Complete. I would like to show each ToD along the x-axis and Count along the y-axis, with a side-by-side bar representation of counts for complete and in-progress shown as the value. So I would like my data to look like this:

[image]

I am struggling to figure out how to do this count based on the Walkthrough Completed column. I went down the path of doing a calculated measure with filters, but I couldn't seem to get what I was looking for. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Group By" menu item to generate the Power Query code for that.

Select your table query, then select "Group By" in the "Home" menu.

Click "Advanced".

Add a grouping for Walkthrough Scheduled Date, Walkthrough Completed, and ToD.

The new Count column should already be correctly configured by default, so you can click "OK".

You should now have the table looking the way you need.